# Disappearing package

Tags: sublimetext3

I am trying to install the Local History package in Sublime 3.  I am behind a proxy and so far have not been able to get package control to work so I am installing the package by pulling the repo into my packages directory.

When I installed it the first time I had Sublime Text 3 open and was surprised to see that the Local History commands appeared with out a restart.  However, they did not seem to work so I restarted Sublime Text.  Package gone.

I have reinstalled it, and stopped and started Sublime multiple times and for whatever reason everytime Sublime starts it removes the entire Local History package from my packages directory.

I have several packages installed in Sublime Text 3 and they all work without issue. This is the first time I have encountered this issue.  Any ideas what may be going on?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. Which directory specifically are you "pulling the repo" into? What does "pulling the repo" mean? Are you using git? Downloading a zip file? Please describe the exact process you are using. When you say Sublime "removes the entire package", what do you mean? Is the directory deleted? How did you determine that?

Comment: It seems pretty clear, why is the Local History package being deleted everytime I restart Sublime?

Comment: If you share the info I asked for, I may be able to tell you. If not, I can't.

Comment: The questions you ask are answered in the original post.  Yes, the directory is removed.  "everytime Sublime starts it removes the entire Local History package from my packages directory".   Yes, I am using git.  And I am placing it into the user packages directory.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **`Preferences -> Settings-User`** and check if **`Local History`** is listed under **`ignored_packages`**. If that's the case the package fails to load. Normally deleting **`Packages/User/Package Control.cache`** directory solves the problem.